# how to get nth row in foreach loop in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

consider i have 2 table like this

remaining | c_remaining

0         |     10

20        |     30

40        |     50

i want 10 - 20 , 30 - 40 and 50 - 0 and i want it in foreach loop

```
@foreach($paid_amounts as $pay_amount)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $pay_amount->c_remaining - $pay_amount->remaining[select 2nd value] }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
```

**how i can how i can skip first value and get value from next from current 1?**

Comment: You need to group values you want to display in single iteration, so you could refer to them using indexes 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to shape the data in the controller itself.

```php
$paid_amounts->map(function($item, $key) use($paid_amounts) {

    $remaining = isset($paid_amounts[$key + 1]) 
        ? $paid_amounts[$key + 1]->remaining 
        : $paid_amounts[0]->remaining;
    
    //Add a new property to each element of the collection
    $item->prop = $item->c_remaining - $remaining;

    return $item;
});
```

Then in the blade view you can use the new property

```
@foreach($paid_amounts as $pay_amount)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $pay_amount->prop }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **really** unclear, but here's what I caught so far...

```
$arr = [0,10,20,30,40,50];

for ($i=1; $i<sizeof($arr);$i++) {
    echo $arr[$i]." ";
}

echo $arr[0];
```